# Why doesn't my Git status show me whether I'm up-to-date with my remote counterpart?

Tags: git

I have tried making some changes and pushed it up to GitHub. From another computer, I fetched the changes. When I do a `git status`, it reports this:

```
On branch MyTestBranch
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

This is strange because *I'm certain that there were changes fetched*. I could even did a merge with those changes fetched!

In fact when I went over to my friend's computer and did a `git status`, I could see this:

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/MyTestBranch' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

But why weren't Git reporting something like my `origin/MyTestBranch` is how many commits ahead or whether my branch is up-to-date with `origin/MyTestBranch`?

Comment: What does `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name "@{u}"` print?  (You may not need the quotes, it depends on which shell you use.)  Alternatively, what does `git branch -vv` show?

Comment: did you tried `git pull origin MyTestBranch`?

Comment: @licon I did not do a pull. I did a fetch first, then followed by a git status, but was surprised that it didn't show me that I'm behind by 1 commit.

Comment: @torek, I have actually merged the branch already. Would the commands still be accurate?

Comment: Yes, although if you've done the merge you'll now be up to date until something else changes.

Comment: @Carven I mean you can try `git pull`. Another trick may help, at first delete your local **MyTestBranch**.  But be sure that deleting your local branch causes any unwanted deleting of your local codes in the branch. If you think that your origin branch has the latest changes then you may delete your local branch & checkout from the origin again by this command `git checkout -b MyTestBranch origin/MyTestBranch` .

Answer (score 39, accepted):

My guess at this point (I'm still waiting for `git branch -vv` or `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name "@{u}"` results) is that you do not have `origin/MyTestBranch` set as the upstream for `MyTestBranch`.

To set a branch as the upstream for the current branch, use:

`git branch --set-upstream-to upstream`<sup>1</sup>

which in this case expands to:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/MyTestBranch
```

To remove an upstream setting, use `git branch --unset-upstream`.

The presence or absence of an upstream setting mainly affects whether `git status` can tell you if you are ahead and/or behind, and whether `git merge` and `git rebase` can do their job with no additional parameters.  So it's basically just a convenience setting.

Normally the upstream is set automatically when you first check out a branch by having `git checkout` create it based on a remote-tracking branch.  For instance, on your first `git clone`, Git runs, at the end, the equivalent of:

```
git checkout master
```

even though you have no `master` yet.  Git then discovers that you have `origin/master` (and no other `remote/master` so that there is no question as to *which* remote to use), and does the equivalent of:

```
git checkout -b master --track origin/master
```

which creates local `master` pointing to the same commit as remote-tracking branch `origin/master`, and setting `origin/master` as the upstream for `master`, all in One Big Do-What-I-Mean Fell Swoop.

When you create a new local branch and have not yet pushed it upstream, there is no `origin/whatever` remote-tracking branch for your local branch to track.<sup>2</sup>  In this case, you have to set the upstream manually, or use `git push -u ...`: the `-u` basically tells `git push` to run `git branch --set-upstream-to` for you (although it's actually all built in to the C code, at this point).

---

<sup>1</sup>If you're stuck with a truly ancient Git (pre-1.8.0) you must use `git branch --set-upstream`, which is tricky to get right, or `git config`, which is also tricky to get right.  If at all possible, upgrade to a modern Git version.

<sup>2</sup>The set of words here—nouns like branch, nouns with adjectives like local branch and remote-tracking branch, and verbs like set-upstream-to and gerunds like tracking—is rather unfortunate.  Git terminology, to put it in a nice short memorable Anglo-Saxon way instead of some polysyllabic neologistic phraseology, sucks rocks.<sup>3</sup>

<sup>3</sup>Or other Anglo-Saxon kick-ass word of choice.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I turns out that it really has to do with the set upstream. Once I did this, it worked out fine now! Strange that it didn't set up the upstream when I first cloned the repo though.

Comment: The key lies in *how* you create the local branch.  If you let `git checkout` create it based on a remote-tracking branch, Git sets that local branch to track the corresponding remote-tracking branch.  If not—if *you* create the local branch—it won't track the remote-tracking branch, even if the remote-tracking branch exists, unless you use `--track` or otherwise request tracking of the remote-tracking branch.  (See what I mean about the terminology?)

Comment: `git branch --set-upstream-to upstream` gave me an "unknown option" error.
I believe you mean `git branch --set-upstream upstream`

Comment: @evt: this means you have a quite old version of Git (pre-1.8.0). `--set-upstream-to` is the replacement / correction for the deprecated `--set-upstream` option.  See [the Git 1.8.0 release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89ea799ffcc5c8a0547d3c9075eb979256ee95b8/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.0.txt#L20-L47) for details.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it should, but before it can do that you need to do a `git fetch` so that Git knows your current branch is behind the remote branch. Then when you do a `git status` you should see that your branch is in fact behind.

Comment: I understand this. Like I've mentioned, I have done a `git fetch`, and I could see there were changes being fetched. But when I do a `git status`, it doesn't tell me whether I'm behind the remote branch. :(

Answer (score 0):

`git remote update` didn't fix the issues with `git status` permanently, but it does check the remote and is easy to remember and type. After running then `git status` tells me I'm behind.

Answer (score -2):

To see how many commits ahead or behind you are, use:

```
$ git checkout # Without any arguments
```

This only works in a repository with a working tree. In bare repositories, I use a script—an old version of [`git-branch-status`](https://github.com/bill-auger/git-branch-status/).

Comment: Didn't work for me, `git checkout` said all ok and then `git pull` pulled down a load of updates

Comment: @Romell Of course you have to use `git fetch` first. Don't use `git pull` because that will do a `fetch` and then trigger a rebase or merge.